# Wordpress theme depends on domain

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, cross-domain

How to show different themes on wordpress site depending on site domain?
All content the same on all domains/themes.
Is it possible? If so, can you recommend the solution?

Example:
1. site1.com - theme1.
2. site2.com - theme2.
3. same content.

Comment: How much of the theme is changing between the domains? Do you just need to change the styles and/logo depending on the domain, but the HTML layout remains the same?

Comment: Also, even if the domain name changes the theme, many of the functions used in the theme will still output the same domain URL entered in the General Settings › "Site Address (URL)." For example, your menu navigation `wp_nav_menu()` will still link to the same domain name.

Comment: Layout is different, but content (text) the same. Is it possible to set links relative? Like "/?=page".

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a custom Must-Use plugin to use the `switch_theme( $stylesheet )` function.

```
<?php

add_filter( 'template', 'wpse_49223_change_theme' );
add_filter( 'option_template', 'wpse_49223_change_theme' );
add_filter( 'option_stylesheet', 'wpse_49223_change_theme' );
function wpse_49223_change_theme( $theme )
{
    $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $domain = str_replace('www.', '', $domain);
    if ( $domain == 'site2.com' )
        $theme = 'theme2';
    else
        $theme = 'theme1';

    return $theme;
}
```

Based on [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49223/show-different-theme-for-admin) solution at WordPress StackExchange.